# jQuery objects comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to the jQuery documentation, "Not All jQuery Objects are Created ===."

"An important detail regarding this "wrapping" behavior is that each wrapped object is unique. This is true even if the object was created with the same selector or contain references to the exact same DOM elements."

[documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)

I know how to work around this but why is this the case? Is this some specific way that JavaScript behaves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Every object in JS is unique, in that `o1 === o2` will not be true unless `o1` and `o2` are pointers to the same object.

```
{ foo: 1 } === { foo: 1 }; // false
```

So jQuery objects simply follow this same rule:

```
var jq1 = $('.foo');
var jq2 = $('.foo');
jq1 === jq2; // false
```

The only exception is if you have variables that actually point to the same jQuery object:

```
var jq3 = jq1;
jq3 === jq1; // true
```